# Grant Azure AD group to access SQL Server

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

We are trying to grant a Azure AD group to one of our SQL Server Database. When try to run the script

```
CREATE USER [Group Name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];
```

The SSMS is giving an error

> Principal 'Group Name' could not be found or this principal type is
>   not supported.

We tried with a different group name without spaces in the name. That worked.

Can somebody let us know what is going wrong?

Regards,

John

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the Security Group Display Name instead of an alias. Make sure also to download the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to enter a support case. In the meantime use your workaround w/o spaces